# How to create a rest API to upload a image file using Apigility?

Tags: api, rest, file-upload, laminas-api-tools

I have try to create rest api for table event in database. This entity has a property is thumb image.
So that when user post a new event then user have to attach a photo to server via api.
I use api POST /event with parameter is multipart/form-data include all properties of event (tile, description, location, link, start_time, end_time, thumb_url).
The thumb_url is the link to the thumb that user post via our api.

But I can not make the api work with tutorial 
https://apigility.org/documentation/recipes/upload-files-to-api

Can someone help me how to do this?

More detail: https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility-skeleton/issues/78

Comment: Please post exact request data, headers etc. Try showing what exactly is going to your app via requestbin for example.